# Enum property in swift 3 can't accessible

Tags: ios, swift3, swifty-json

In my program, I want to use SwiftyJSONModel library. But it will give me following error when implementing Model class

[image]

Answer (score 0):

JSONObject's `PropertyKey.RawValue` is a `String` so use a string value:

```
enum PropertyKey: String {
    case error = "Error"
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

            /* Here you can see the proper access to the enum case 
               do the same in your code
            */

            let str: String = PropertyKey.error.rawValue
    }
}
```